# What does the Pi stand for in the reaction for biological nitrogen fixation?

Tags: chemical-biology, notation

In the reaction for biological nitrogen fixation, what does the Pi stand for in the products? 
$$\ce{N2 + 8H + 8e- + 16 ATP -> 2NH3 + H2 + 16ADP + 16 P_{i}}$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It stands for inorganic phosphate (Pi). When ATP is broken down into ADP, energy is released along with a phosphate. You can visualise this if you look at the structure of ATP. ADP is then also able to be broken down into AMP and more Pi